# Can I specify a range with the IntegerValidator attribute on a custom ConfigurationSection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, configurationsection

I have a class containing the following [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx):

```
namespace DummyConsole {
  class TestingComponentSettings: ConfigurationSection {

    [ConfigurationProperty("waitForTimeSeconds", IsRequired=true)]
    [IntegerValidator(MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 100, ExcludeRange = false)]
    public int WaitForTimeSeconds
    {
        get { return (int)this["waitForTimeSeconds"]; }
        set { this["waitForTimeSeconds"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("loginPage", IsRequired = true, IsKey=false)]
    public string LoginPage
    {
        get { return (string)this["loginPage"]; }
        set { this["loginPage"] = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

I then have the following in my .config file:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="TestingComponentSettings" 
           type="DummyConsole.TestingComponentSettings, DummyConsole"/>
</configSections>
<TestingComponentSettings waitForTimeSeconds="20" loginPage="myPage" />
```

When I then attempt to use this configuration section I get the following error:

```
var Testing = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TestingComponentSettings")
             as TestingComponentSettings;
```

> **ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled**
>
> The value for the property 'waitForTimeSeconds' is not valid. The error is: The value must be inside the range 1-100.

If I change the `IntegerValidator` to have an ExcludeRage = true, I (obviously) get:

> **ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled**
>
> The value for the property 'waitForTimeSeconds' is not valid. The error is: The value must not be in the range 1-100

If I then change the value of the property in the .config to a number higher than 100, it works.

If I change the validator to just have a `MaxValue` of 100 it works, but will also accept a value of -1.

Is it possible to use the `IntegerValidatorAttribute` with a range like this?

**Edit to add**

Confirmed as an [issue by Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=526491).

Comment: The Microsoft link has been updated today with a solution. Apparently if a default value is not specified, it uses "0" as the default value. 0 is, of course, outside the range 1-100.

The "solution" is to add a DefaultValue= parameter to the ConfigurationProperty attribute with a default value that is in the range. Unfortunately this means that you're imposing a default value which might not be what you want/need.

I've been having this problem, too. Glad I stumbled across this question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [Skrud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218/skrud) points out, MS have updated the connect issue:

> The reported issue is because of a quirk in how the configuration system handles validators. Each numeric configuration property has a default value - even if one is not specified. When a default is not specified the value 0 is used. In this example the configuration property ends up with a default value that is not in the valid range specified by the integer validator. As a result configuration parsing always fails.
>
> To fix this, change the configuration property definition to include a default value that is within the range of 1 to 100:
>
> ```
> [ConfigurationProperty("waitForTimeSeconds", IsRequired=true, 
>                        DefaultValue="10")]
> ```

This does mean that the property will have a default, but I don't actually see that as a major issue - we're saying that it should have a value that falls within a "sensible" range, and should be prepared to set a sensible default.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me. In my case, I specifically wanted to require the option to be specified in the config file, so I didn't want to set a default value. But, it turns out that if you mark a field as required that fact takes precedence and the default value is never actually _used_ except to keep validation from firing prematurely. It's a little counter-intuitive, but it works.